# Some streams doesn't play on iOS AVPlayer.

Tags: audio, avplayer, http-live-streaming, bitrate, avplayerlayer

I have a weird problem with playing some streams. Those streams don't play, and AVPlayerItem returns the error "Cannot Decode". By inspecting it on different software (ie VLC Media Player), I noticed that the problem is with audio, mean that all streams with audio bitrate of 128 kb/s and higher are not playable. Is it possible to convert this bitrate "on the fly" to lower one, or is there another approach? I use AVplayerLayer, AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem to play streams.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an unplayable file?

Comment: AVPlayer supports audio bitrates of 128 kb/s and higher. The problem is probably in the encoder. Which encoder software do you use - for example ffmpeg, wowza? And how is it configured?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm seeing similar issues from time to time.